# Reconnect with puka python library for RabbitMQ

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I use puka python library to connect a few clients connected to RabbitMQ which time out after a while when the connection is not used. The current puka API offers only connection, and no support for reconnection. I've tried to use the normal connection functions, but I receive errors since I overwrite _client and promise variables. How can I reconnect a process to rabbitMQ without breaking the other connections? Thanks!

The current code looks like this, and is used by multiple processes:

```
_client = puka.Client(amqp_url=URL)
promise = _client.connect()
_client.wait(promise)

promise = _client.exchange_declare(exchange='notifications')
_client.wait(promise)

promise = _client.queue_declare(queue=_queue, durable=True)
_client.wait(promise)

promise = _client.queue_bind(exchange='notifications', queue=_queue, routing_key=_queue)
_client.wait(promise)

consume_promise = _client.basic_consume(queue=_queue)

while not CONDITION:
    try:
        result = _client.wait(consume_promise, timeout=1)
        if not result:
            continue
    except puka.ConnectionBroken as e:
        # An error is raised here when it disconnects from Rabbit
        continue

    _client.basic_ack(result)
```